# YA Sci Fi - Failing colony ship in orbit around a red planet, some kind of psychic link with the planet, twins, and epiphytes

Tags: story-identification

Sometime around 1992-1995, I read a Young Adult science fiction book in a New Zealand library (so it could have been a little known NZ or Australian writer - and it was Stokes Valley library if that helps).

The main character was a teenage girl on a colony ship in orbit around a red planet - not sure if it was Mars, feels like another solar system all together.
The colony ship isn't doing very well, for reasons no one can explain. It should be self-sustaining, but fertility is low in plants, animals, non-existent in humans. Most plants aren't doing that well.
People seem creeped out by the red planet and have closed most of the viewing platforms of the planet.
But some things are thriving - plants that are epiphytes, or airborn, or particular colours? Of the animals they do manage to breed, there are a lot more twins?
I feel like there was some kind of mystical thing going on, like, humans have a connection to 'Gaia' on Earth, and they aren't surviving in space without that, but the main character is really fascinated by the red planet.
And then - no idea what happened, but some kind of mystical link is established with the new planet, the colony starts to work, while being influenced in new directions by the new planet, and the first humans on the colony ship, twins of course, are born. And I think they were psychic.

Comment: You've already provided a load of information, but take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can [edit] in anything else.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly suspect you are referring to Asimov's [*Nemesis*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9563). It fits most of the elements you mention, especially the colony ship and the teenage girl who gains telepathic communications with the planet's life forms.

Comment: Except for the twins thing, this is Asimov's Nemesis all right.